# Socket.io constantly polling... should it be doing this?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a node server and a web page connected via socket.io.  I noticed in the browser console that it is outputting

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://my_url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1418944327412-412&sid=vqLTUtW3QhNLwQG8AAAA".
```

and

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://my_url/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1418944385398-415&sid=vqLTUtW3QhNLwQG8AAAA".
```

every few seconds. Should it be doing this or am I missing a setting. I'm really only looking to send data back and forth explicitly via the socket. Perhaps I'm missing something in the set up.

Client side is basically

```
var socket = io("http://my_url");
```

with the usual event listeners. Server side is

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

I tried placing this on the server side

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

but that seemed to kill it.

Comment: Looks like your server side code is sending messages to the client. It cant be understood unless u share code snippets of both server n client

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `socket.io` implementation (when using webSockets) sends regular (every few seconds) heartbeat and response packets to constantly verify that the connection is alive and well.  This is normal.

These packets are not actual http requests (they are websocket data packets) so there should not be full-on http packets going on unless `socket.io` is not actually using the webSocket protocol, but is instead using HTTP long polling.  `socket.io` will use the webSocket protocol as long as it is supported in the client (which it should be in all modern browsers nowadays).

You may have to be careful about how you interpret requests in a debugger.  A `socket.io` connection starts its life as an http request with some custom headers and all debuggers will show this initial http request.  If webSocket is supported at both ends, then the server will return a response which "upgrades" the connection to the webSocket protocol.  That same TCP socket which started out as a TCP request, then becomes a webSocket connection.  Subsequent webSockets messages sent on the webSocket then flow over that TCP socket.  It is up to the debugger on how it might display that traffic.  In the Chrome debugger, you have to open the original http connection and then ask to see websocket traffic and only then can you actually see webSocket packets.  But, I could imagine in other debuggers that weren't as webSocket saavy, they might show subsequent packets as related to that original HTTP connection (I haven't looked at how debuggers other than Chrome show webSocket traffic).

The only other reason I can think of that a client would be repeatedly sending HTTP connection requests is if the connection keeps dropping for some reason so the client keeps reconnecting every time the connection drops.  `socket.io` has settings that can control how often/vigorously the client tries to reconnect when the connection is lost, though if you have connection issues, then you really need to figure out why there are connection issues rather than change the reconnect settings.